# Does creating a new Qt Window with no parent also create a new thread?

Tags: c++, qt, qthread

My question is two parts:

1. Is `mainWindow` spawned in a thread other than the one running main()?
2. How does `mainWindow` not immediately go out of scope when main() returns?

In the below example a window is created, shown, and main returns almost immediately.

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

MainWindowExample.pro

```
#-------------------------------------------------
#
# Project created by QtCreator 2016-05-23T10:55:03
#
#-------------------------------------------------

QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MainWindowExample
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS  += mainwindow.h

FORMS    += mainwindow.ui
```

Comment: This is not part of the documented contract. If you need to know about implementation details, you have to add the specific Qt version you are using, and the designated platform.

Comment: 1. you usually have only one gui thread 2. it does, but `a.exec()` only returns after the main window is closed

Comment: @KarstenKoop 1. Doesn't quite answer the question, but 2. is good to know. Let me give another example: if the MainWindow thread creates a new window but does not give that window a parent (`parent=0`), then does it spawn a new thread or do they both operate on the same thread?

Comment: It depends on your implementation. Again, this is not documented. If you need to know for your specific version of Qt, and designated target platform, simply single-step through the code. You won't get an answer any more concise than *"Usually you only have a single GUI thread."*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. No new thread is created for `mainWindow`
2. The `mainWindow` event loop is executed in scope of `a.exec()` - it blocks until application exits (for example - last top-level window is closed).

So `mainWindow` does not go out of scope, because it is `main` that executes everything.

Check it using code like:

```
std::cout << "starting application event loop" << std::endl;
const int ret = a.exec();
std::cout << "after exec" << std::endl; // or any other code here
return ret;
```

From [QApplication](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html#exec)  doc:

> Enters the main event loop and waits until exit() is called, then returns the value that was set to exit() (which is 0 if exit() is called via quit()).

Comment: *"In the [...] example a window is created, shown, and main returns almost immediately."* - Your answer doesn't address this at all. Besides giving the impression that undocumented implementation details were contractual. This is not the case.

Comment: OP must be mistaken about main returning immediately, as this would destroy MainWindow and either close whole application or cause some crash. QApplication::exec being blocking method is quite well documented...

Comment: @Hcorg is correct, I was mistaken about returning immediately. Thank you for the counterexample and showing me how to check this.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is mainWindow spawned in a thread other than the one running `main()`?

No. In fact, it'd be undefined behavior to do so. You can only construct `QWidget` descendants in the main thread.

The [Threads and Objects](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/threads-qobject.html#qobject-reentrancy) documentation topic covers that:

> > Although QObject is reentrant, the GUI classes, notably QWidget and all its subclasses, are not reentrant. They can only be used from the main thread. As noted earlier, QCoreApplication::exec() must also be called from that thread.*

#### How does mainWindow not immediately go out of scope when `main()` returns?

But it does!

`main()` returns when `a.exec()` returns, and that happens only when you quit your application. By default, your application quits automatically when the last visible window is closed.

Comment: *"No. In fact, it'd be undefined behavior to do so. You can only construct QWidget descendants in the main thread."* - Got any reference to official documentation?

Comment: @IInspectable Seriously? There you go. Third google result when you search for "qwidget thread site:doc.qt.io". The rest of your objections might not be all explicitly documented in the way you wish, but there's no way to implement them any other way, short of making everything synchronized to an extent where there being other threads would be immaterial (but of course performing like molasses). Furthermore, since `QWidget` is-a `QObject`, its `thread()` has well understood semantics. Qt can't change the `thread()` by itself!